# FatalError: attribute name expected in valid XML with DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have 2 files (XML and DTD) in my project and I must valid it. I have declarated out of XML document. I use XML Copy Editor to valid and I get communication "FatalError at line 9, column 25: attribute name expected" - it's mean something wrong with element "kraj_prod", but I cannot find what's going on. Element "kraj_prod" haven't got attributes. XML document is well-formed. DTD document in XML Copy Editor give me syntax error at 1st element (kino). Below is my code DTD and XML wrote in polish language.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE kino SYSTEM "filmy.dtd">
<kino>
    <nazwa>Kino Pojutrze</nazwa>
    <film>
        <tytul id="9080" wersja="napisy">Przemytnik</tytul>
        <rezyser><imie>Clint</imie> <nazwisko>Eastwood</nazwisko></rezyser>
        <scenarzysta><imie>Nick</imie> <nazwisko>Schenk</nazwisko></scenarzysta>
        <kraj_prod>USA</kraj_prod>
        <rok_prod>2018</rok_prod>
        <gatunek>dramat</gatunek>
        <gatunek>kryminał</gatunek>
        <czas_trw czas="minuty">116</czas_trw>
        <obsada>
            <aktor><imie>Clint</imie> <nazwisko>Eastwood</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Bradley</imie> <nazwisko>Cooper</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Laurence</imie> <nazwisko>Fishburne</nazwisko></aktor>
        </obsada>
    </film>
    <film>
        <tytul id="9293" wersja="">Ja teraz kłamię</tytul>
        <rezyser><imie>Paweł</imie> <nazwisko>Borowski</nazwisko></rezyser>
        <scenarzysta><imie>Paweł</imie> <nazwisko>Borowski</nazwisko></scenarzysta>
        <kraj_prod>Polska</kraj_prod>
        <kraj_prod>Holandia</kraj_prod>
        <rok_prod>2019</rok_prod>
        <gatunek>komedia</gatunek>
        <gatunek>thriller</gatunek>
        <czas_trw czas="minuty"></czas_trw>
        <obsada>
            <aktor><imie>Maja</imie> <nazwisko>Ostaszewska</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Joanna</imie> <nazwisko>Kulig</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Rafał</imie> <nazwisko>Maćkowiak</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Agata</imie> <nazwisko>Buzek</nazwisko></aktor>
        </obsada>
    </film>
    <film>
        <tytul id="9352" wersja="dubbing">Król Lew</tytul>
        <rezyser><imie>Jon</imie> <nazwisko>Favreau</nazwisko></rezyser>
        <scenarzysta><imie>Jeff</imie> <nazwisko>Nathanson</nazwisko></scenarzysta>
        <kraj_prod>USA</kraj_prod>
        <rok_prod>2019</rok_prod>
        <gatunek>animowany</gatunek>
        <gatunek>familijny</gatunek>
        <gatunek>przygodowy</gatunek>
        <czas_trw czas="minuty"></czas_trw>
        <obsada></obsada>
    </film>
    <film>
        <tytul id="6827" wersja="napisy">Wonder Woman</tytul>
        <rezyser><imie>Patty</imie> <nazwisko>Jenkins</nazwisko></rezyser>
        <scenarzysta><imie>Allan</imie> <nazwisko>Heinberg</nazwisko></scenarzysta>
        <scenarzysta><imie>Geoff</imie> <nazwisko>Johns</nazwisko></scenarzysta>
        <kraj_prod>USA</kraj_prod>
        <rok_prod>2017</rok_prod>
        <gatunek>akcja</gatunek>
        <gatunek>sci-fi</gatunek>
        <czas_trw czas="minuty">139</czas_trw>
        <obsada>
            <aktor><imie>Gal</imie> <nazwisko>Gadot</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Robin</imie> <nazwisko>Wright</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Chris</imie> <nazwisko>Pine</nazwisko></aktor>
        </obsada>
    </film>
    <film>
        <tytul id="6750" wersja="napisy">Piraci z Karaibów: Zemsta Salazara</tytul>
        <rezyser><imie>Joachim</imie> <nazwisko>Ronning</nazwisko></rezyser>
        <rezyser><imie>Espen</imie> <nazwisko>Sandberg</nazwisko></rezyser>
        <scenarzysta><imie>Jeff</imie> <nazwisko>Nathanson</nazwisko></scenarzysta>
        <kraj_prod>USA</kraj_prod>
        <rok_prod>2017</rok_prod>
        <gatunek>fantasy</gatunek>
        <gatunek>przygodowy</gatunek>
        <czas_trw czas="minuty">135</czas_trw>
        <obsada>
            <aktor><imie>Johnny</imie> <nazwisko>Deep</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Javier</imie> <nazwisko>Bardem</nazwisko></aktor>
            <aktor><imie>Orlando</imie> <nazwisko>Bloom</nazwisko></aktor>
        </obsada>
    </film>
</kino>
```

DTD document (filmy.dtd):

```
<!ELEMENT kino (nazwa,film+)>
<!ELEMENT nazwa (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT film (tytul, rezyser+, scenarzysta*, kraj_prod+, rok_prod, gatunek+, czas_trw?, obsada?)>
<!ELEMENT tytul (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST tytul
id ID #REQUIRED
wersja NMTOKEN #IMPLIED "">

<!ELEMENT rezyser (#PCDATA, imie, nazwisko)>
<!ELEMENT scenarzysta (imie, nazwisko)>
<!ELEMENT imie (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nazwisko (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT kraj_prod (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rok_prod (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gatunek (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT czas_trw (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST czas_trw
czas NMTOKEN #FIXED "minuty">

<!ELEMENT obsada (aktor*)>
<!ELEMENT aktor (imie, nazwisko)>
```

I wanted good valid of my XML and DTD documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of this line:

```
wersja NMTOKEN #IMPLIED "">
```

You can't have the default `""` after `#IMPLIED` ([see here for more details](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-DefaultDecl)).

It should look like:

```
wersja NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>
```

You could replace the `#IMPLIED` with `""` if the type was CDATA instead of NMTOKEN (`""` is an invalid default value for [NMTOKEN](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Nmtoken)).

Are you sure you really want to use NMTOKEN? The XML has an empty value for that attribute.

Also, your declaration for `rezyser` is incorrect. You can only declare [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) (element containing both PCDATA and child elements) one way:

```
<!ELEMENT rezyser (#PCDATA|imie|nazwisko)*>
```

One last thing, since your `id` attribute is declared as `ID`, they can't start with a number. They have to be valid [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name)'s. You'll have to change the [start character](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for no answer from your help but I found error from "rezyser" and "wersja" as you prompted. Parent "rezyser" have 2 child: imie and nazwisko, not #PCDATA, so there should be fine

```
<!ELEMENT rezyser (imie,nazwisko)*>
```

Next is "wersja" who should be like you wrote, so i change it.
Last is "id" who should be #CDATA, becouse in the future I declarate it more in XSD document.

Thanks for your help about XML and DTD.
In this step I must close thread, becouse after that changes, program XML Copy Editor and widget from Notepad++ valid my documents (XML and DTD) :)